# How to get contacts on Telegram

Tags: node.js, architecture, telegram, telegram-bot

I use node.js module for Telegram bot.
I'm trying to get the user's contact on telegram using telegram API.
Telegram API has 2 types: [Bot API and Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api).

I think Bot API can not get the user's contacts.
In Telegram API there is the method [`contact.getContacts`](https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.getContacts). But I don't know how to use it.

How can I get the contacts on Telegram?

Answer (score 5):

1. this code will give you the contact, user shares his/her contact with your bot , user types command '/special' will be prompted with button to allow bot to get contact and on agreeing in your node server you may log contact info remember to declare Markup ---->

   ```
   //declare Markup 
   const {Extra,Markup}= Telegraf;

   bot.command('special', (ctx) => {
   return ctx.reply('Special buttons keyboard', Extra.markup((markup) => {
   return markup.resize()
   .keyboard([
   markup.contactRequestButton('contact')
   ])
   }))
   })
   //listens for the click on contact button
   bot.on('contact', (ctx) => {
   console.log(ctx.update.message.contact);
   //logs { phone_number: '254*******',
   //first_name: 'nelsonBlack',
   //user_id: 73***** }

   })
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Bot API can get contact info too; I think it is easier in this case.

You can try reply keyboard with [request_contact](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton). If the user clicks it, you will receive message update with [Contact](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact) field.

Comment: Great and one extra point. You can't get a user's contact without his permission. that's why the method is called `request_contact` not get_contact.